# lazy loading from url mixes images on scroll in a grid view

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-adapter

I am working on an application where i have to lazy load images from the internet and put them in a gridview.
The problem is that when i load these images, they get mixed on the scroll of this gridview.
for example, the picture supposed to appear in the first position appears in the 3rd and so on..
Can anyone help me please ?

This is my mainactivity code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivityLoading extends Activity {

    GridView grid;
    LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_loading);

        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        // Create custom adapter for listview
        adapter=new LazyImageLoadAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this, mStrings);

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //Refresh cache directory downloaded images
                adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Remove adapter refference from list
        grid.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
    {
        String tempValues = mStrings[mPosition];

        Toast.makeText(MainActivityLoading.this,
                "Image URL : "+tempValues,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Image urls used in LazyImageLoadAdapter.java file

    private String[] mStrings={
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Sad-icon.png", 
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Happy-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Crying-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Cool-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-In-love-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Lol-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Surprised-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Tongue-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Wink-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Sad-icon.png", 
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Happy-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Crying-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Cool-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-In-love-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Lol-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Surprised-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Tongue-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Wink-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Sad-icon.png", 
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Happy-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Crying-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Cool-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-In-love-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Lol-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Surprised-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Tongue-icon.png",
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Wink-icon.png"
            };
}
```

This is my LazyImageLoadAdapter class code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] mStrings;
    private Context mContext;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Context context, Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        mStrings=d;
        mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mStrings.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {    
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(mStrings[position], imageView);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        grid.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }


    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{          
        private int mPosition;

       OnItemClickListener(int position){
             mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            MainActivityLoading sct = (MainActivityLoading)activity;
            sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
        }              
    }
```

This is my ImageLoader class code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    // Initialize MemoryCache
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

    FileCache fileCache;

    //Create Map (collection) to store image and image url in key value pair
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(
                                           new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    //handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context){

        fileCache = new FileCache(context);

        // Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of
        // threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    }

    // default image shown in list (Before online image download)
    final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //Store image and url in Map
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

        //Check image is stored in MemoryCache Map or not (see MemoryCache.java)
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if(bitmap!=null){
            // if image is stored in MemoryCache Map then
            // Show image in listview row
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else
        {
            //queue Photo to download from url
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);

            //Before downloading image show default image
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        // Store image and url in PhotoToLoad object
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);

        // pass PhotoToLoad object to PhotosLoader runnable class
        // and submit PhotosLoader runnable to executers to run runnable
        // Submits a PhotosLoader runnable task for execution 

        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                //Check if image already downloaded
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                // download image from web url
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);

                // set image data in Memory Cache
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;

                // Get bitmap to display
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);

                // Causes the Runnable bd (BitmapDisplayer) to be added to the message queue.
                // The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.
                // BitmapDisplayer run method will call
                handler.post(bd);

            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        //CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        // Download image file from web
        try {

            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();

            // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file
            // if file not exist then it will create file
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

            // See Utils class CopyStream method
            // It will each pixel from input stream and
            // write pixels to output stream (file)
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);

            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();

            //Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
            // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);

            return bitmap;

        } catch (Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
               memoryCache.clear();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

        try {

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

          //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

            // Set width/height of recreated image
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=85;

            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with current scale values
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){

        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        //Check url is already exist in imageViews MAP
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            // Show bitmap on UI
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //Clear cache directory downloaded images and stored data in maps
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

This is my MemoryCache class code :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

    //Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));

   //current allocated size
    private long size=0;

    //max memory cache folder used to download images in bytes
    private long limit=1000000;

    public MemoryCache(){

        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){

        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;

            return cache.get(id);

        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){

            //least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
             // Clear cache
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

This is my FileCache class code :

```
import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;

public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){

        //Find the dir at SDCARD to save cached images

        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                                     android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            //if SDCARD is mounted (SDCARD is present on device and mounted)
            cacheDir = new File(
                       android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        }
        else
        {
            // if checking on simulator the create cache dir in your application context
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if(!cacheDir.exists()){
            // create cache dir in your application context
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //Identify images by hashcode or encode by URLEncoder.encode.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        // list all files inside cache directory
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        //delete all cache directory files
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

This is my Utils class code :

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {

            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              //Read byte from input stream

              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;

              //Write byte from output stream
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post code only that is related to your issue. One doesn't have time to go through your entire application's source code and find the issue.

Comment: The problem is, i am new to android and i never had an issue like that, so i don't know where is the issue or why is there an issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing all these hard works yourself. Android sdk already has the dedicated library for bitmap caching and worker thread process.
It will save you lots of effort and make the codes cleaner

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)

Personally this is my favorite lazy image loader, it works well on both low and high resolution images
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I guess the "wheel wasn't round enough"